# Set default selection to Magic suggest

Tags: javascript, magicsuggest

I have a Magic suggest box in my application. 
For that I want to set default selected values.
I have JSON object as well to bind the data. But I didn't find any option like how to make them selected.

Is there any option in Magic suggest?

Please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the 'value' option:

```
$('#ms-gmail').magicSuggest({
    resultAsString: true,
    width: 590,
    value: ['john@kennedy.com'],
    data: 'marilyn@monroe.com, mother@teresa.com,...,jimmy@wales.com'
});
```

The above example sets the default selected value to 'john@kennedy.com'

See http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/

Comment: OK, but please mark it as the correct answer - it'll help other people googling for your question.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple values ?

Comment: Not sure, sounds like a new question.