# Magic Suggest - Pre-select multiple items from MVC Model

Tags: model-view-controller, magicsuggest

I'm looking for a way to populate the Magic Suggest control with multiple values.  I am using ASP.NET MVC and would like to set these values based on properties in the model.

**Part 1:**  Magic Suggest Support for Multiple Values?  A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877978/set-default-selection-to-magic-suggest) on SOF addresses adding a single value but not multiple.  Is this possible?

**Part 2**: Ideally, I'd like to bind the control the MVC model somehow.  If this is not possible, I'd at least like to set the pre-selected values dynamically.  I have access the model via razor syntax.  Something similar to how Magic Suggest allows you to set the data perhaps.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
            data: '/controller/GetValuesJson?mealId=@Model.Id',
            valueField: 'Id',
            displayField: 'Name',
            /* The property below allows pre-selection */
            /* How can I use Razor and set from my MVC model?* /
            value: */ Some Code Here */
        });
    });
```

**EDIT: Part 2:** Attempting to set the value property by any variable seems to fail.  I've tried variations of strings, quotes etc. to no avail.

```
 var returnedIds = [1,2]; // Or some variable population 
         $(function () {
            $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
                data: '/controller/GetValuesJson?mealId=@Model.Id',
                valueField: 'Id',
                displayField: 'Name',
                value: [returnedIds]
            });
        });
```

**Solved:** Thanks to @karlipoppins posts below and some tinkering.

```
$(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSomeValuesJson")',
            data: { Id: 1},
            type: 'post',
            success: function (returnedVal)
            {
                var ms = $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest(
                { 
                    data: '/Meal/GetSomeValuesJson?&Id=@Model.Id',
                    valueField: 'Id',
                    displayField: 'Name',
                });

                ms.setValue(returnedVal);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: If I might add a suggestion/tip to this $.ajax approach (thank you, by the way!), you can put a spinner/loading .gif inside the #magicsuggest div and it will be replaced by the control when it loads - really quick and handy trick to let the user know something is happening, in case the ajax call takes some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to set multiple values when the component is loaded up. On your code you are using `Id` as the value field and `Name` as the displayField.

This means that magicsuggest is expecting `data` to be in the form of

`[{"Id": 1, "Name": "hello"}, {"Id": 2, "Name": "world"}, {"Id": 3, "Name": "no"}]`

Now to set multiple values, you can

1) do that when defining the component in js:

```
    $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
        data: '/controller/GetValuesJson?mealId=@Model.Id',
        valueField: 'Id',
        displayField: 'Name',
        value: [1, 2] // select 'hello', 'world'
    });
```

2) or you can also define it directly in your DOM containing field:

```
<div id="magicsuggest" value="[1,2]"></div>
```

and then create the component like this:

```
    $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
        data: '/controller/GetValuesJson?mealId=@Model.Id',
        valueField: 'Id',
        displayField: 'Name'
    });
```

See both examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpz6y/

Cheers

Comment: I tried the code above and it works great to solve Part 1 of the question (selecting multiple).  + 1 Thank you!  Part 2 (setting these values dynamically) remains more elusive. As you note, the data field accepts a call to a controller to populate dynamically.  I have not been able to find a similar option for the selected values.

Comment: There is no way to directly bind the selected values. You have to do that yourself, using `$.ajax` to retrieve the values and then use the method `setValue()` on the component.