# how to set magicsuggest exist value

Tags: jquery, json, magicsuggest

I using http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/ for my site Tags function

in the edit page. I want show the existing tags.

But I can't set it.

in the php, I had foreach all tags to page, but **How to insert to magicsuggest for existing tags**

anyone can tell me how can I do?

now js

```
$(function() {
    $('#ms').magicSuggest({
        placeholder: 'Tag Here',
        hideTrigger: true,
        data: 'get_tags.php',
        valueField: 'name',
        displayField: 'name',
        maxEntryLength: 8,
        maxSelection: 5,
        maxDropHeight: 145,
        width:100,
    });

});
```

I test these tutorial. But not work.

https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/issues/15

[Set default selection to Magic suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877978/set-default-selection-to-magic-suggest)

Comment: What is get_tags.php returning? Can you also add the html for your magicsuggest?

Comment: data: 'get_tags.php' is php suggest tag from jons send to html. just suggest, I need set existing tags now

Comment: You'll need to post your code if you want help solving your problem - there are no problems with what you've posted already.